# Erro de português em motivo de fechamento

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, localização

Não sei como não percebemos isso antes, mas o motivo de fechamento para quando a pergunta não é clara tem um erro (possivelmente de digitação):

> não é claro o que você está **perguntado**

deveria ser

> não é claro o que você está **perguntando**

Comment: [Normal](http://blogdomariomagalhaes.blogosfera.uol.com.br/2014/03/05/161-anos-depois-o-new-york-times-corrige-erro/)... :D

Comment: Dvee ser plea fmora cmoo nsoso crerébo itenreprta as plravaas!

Comment: Talvez seja melhor: *Não é claro oque está* ***sendo*** *perguntado*

Comment: @Andrey Se for pra mudar, eu mudaria para "A pergunta não é clara", mas talvez achem muito seco.

Comment: @bfavaretto Achei meio seco sim. O engraçado é que eu sempre li com o ***sendo*** ali no meio, só agora percebi que ele na verdade não tá ali. XD

Comment: É normal, nós já nem lemos isso, é cada um já lê como quer ahahahah. Fica a minha sugestão: 
"Não é claro o que você está a perguntar"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvido, vai pro ar no próximo build.